# Can I tell R to create an object in case that that object does not exist yet?

Tags: r, replace, na, missing-data, metafor

I'm running a large number of meta-analyses with metafor. To get an overview of the results, I wanted to put together vectors containing the main estimates (to combine them in a dataframe later on). Yet, for some of these calculations, I do not have enough primary studies yet, so R will not be able to create a model for this particular domain. Hence, I will get an error message when I try to create a vector at the end.

```
library(metafor)
r1<-c(NA,NA)
n1<-c(NA,NA)
data1<-data.frame(r1,n1)
escalc1<-escalc(measure="COR", ri=r1,ni=n1, data = data1, method=REML)
rma1<-rma(yi,vi, data=escalc1)
#note the program will not be able to calculate rma1, because k = 0.

r2<-c(.3,.2)
n2<-c(100,200)
data2<-data.frame(r2,n2)
escalc2<-escalc(measure="COR", ri=r2,ni=n2, data = data2, method=REML)
rma2<-rma(yi,vi, data=escalc2)
#it will create an object for rma2 though

estimates<-c(rma1$beta, rma2$beta)
#as rma2 exists but rma1 doesn't, R will no let me create a vector here
```

Is there a way to tell R to check if the object exists first and to put in NAs for all cases where no object has been created yet? Specifically, I want R to replace rma1$beta (which does not exist) with NA in the last line of code. Is that possible?

Comment: How many analyses will you be running? Assuming you have plenty of actual data, will you be doing all of them manually like in the example or do you have some loop running over data and automating the process?

Comment: Use `tryCatch`.

Comment: I will do 90 analyses, not counting additional moderator tests. And I will perform all of them manually because I am not an experienced coder and have never used loops before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch` to tell R what to do as an alternative if an error occurs, e.g.,

```
library(metafor)
r1<-c(NA,NA)
n1<-c(NA,NA)
data1<-data.frame(r1,n1)
escalc1<-escalc(measure="COR", ri=r1,ni=n1, data = data1)
e1 <- tryCatch({
  rma1<-rma(yi,vi, data=escalc1); 
  rma1$beta}, error = function(e) NA)


r2<-c(.3,.2)
n2<-c(100,200)
data2<-data.frame(r2,n2)
escalc2<-escalc(measure="COR", ri=r2,ni=n2, data = data2)
e2 <- tryCatch({
  rma2<-rma(yi,vi, data=escalc2); 
  rma2$beta}, error = function(e) NA)

estimates<-c(e1, e2)
#[1]        NA 0.2356358
```